# JModelLegacy::getInstance error Call to a member function on boolean

Tags: joomla-3.6

I am trying this code in my module but getting error

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_idlmessaging/models','IdlmessagingModel');
$questionmodel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Question', 'IdlmessagingModel');
$questionid = '2'; //We used here '1' article id
$question= $questionmodel->getData($questionid );
```

**Error:** "Call to a member function getData on boolean"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
JLoader::import('question', JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_idlmessaging/models');
$questionmodel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Question', 'IdlmessagingModel');
$questionid = '2'; //We used here '1' article id
$question= $questionmodel->getData($questionid );
```